# Best practice for Time Out values for SOAP/REST

Tags: rest, soap, network-programming

I'm working in a team running a Integration Platform for a enterprise with offices and servers all over world and we are struggling with teams building SOAP and/or REST services that has very slow response times (+30 seconds) and out integration platforms products will time out those requests.

I have tried to tell these teams that a SOAP service that responding slower than 5-10 seconds is no longer to be considered as a synchronous service and the integration should be built differently, for example using out WMQ messaging platform or do long polling etc..

I'm getting challenged to prove my point so can anyone point out any industry standard / best practice etc in regards to execution times and time outs for SOAP and REST?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no industry standard on this.30s is obviously a very slow API response time, and depending on scale, may cause a synchronous application to crash.

My best advice would be to show them,given your scale and infrastructure, the time it would take a sync application to crash.I believe that period would be short enough to make them change their minds.